# How can I remove php interpreter characters from html text with jquery?

Tags: jquery, str-replace

I get an html Text from my database and it looks kind of weird:

```
Cat (Friends of \"Monkey\"")" Dog 4x4\"",- Friends\n- 2-Dogfood\n- 1 x Catfood 4\""x4\"" \n- 1 x Monkeyfood \n- Toys \n- Brush \n- Set of Toys"

- Animals \n- 123 / N23\n- Monkeys together\n- 4 x 400ft. Farm rabits\n- 2 x 1000ft. Horses Cats\n- Group with all farm members\n- Flowers \n- Food\n- Love 400 -Random\r\n- 2-Countries\r\n- 1 x Hotel 4\"x4\"" \r\n- 1 x Shelter \r\n- Plate \r\n- Pillow \r\n- Cards"
```

I try to remove all characters that do not belong into the text with jquery

```
var str = input.replace(/\\r|\n|\r/g, "");
```

But it doesn't seemed to be removed correctly. The \n for example is still in the text.

Comment: You've used `\\r` but not `\\n`?  `\n` = new line - if it's showing as "\n" and not as a newline, then you'll need `\\n`

Comment: Ah ok, I understand!